# I only have Office 2013. How do I access a Sharepoint 2010 Workspace?

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-office-2013, sharepoint-2010

When I only have Office 2013 available to me, is there still a way to sync with a Sharepoint 2010 Workspace for offline access? e.g. will skydrive pro work with a Sharepoint 2010 Workspace? Or is there some other method?

Or is it the case that I still must have the Office 2010 files & license for the Sharepoint Workspace 2010 client?

Answer (score 0):

OneDrive will not sync with 2010 - you need to keep SharePoint work space to sync with 2010.

However if you don't want to  keep work space around you can..

If you just want these synced locally but are not worried about offline access - you can map document libraries like network shares.

If you need offline access - you can use outlook to connect to a document library.  I think this is a bit clunky but it can work.

You can also try out free Outlook plugin from Harmon.IE ( https://harmon.ie/freedownload ) as an alternative. It works better than the default library sync in Outlook.